# If $x(2+\sqrt3)=y(2-\sqrt3)$ then find the value of $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{y+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My attempt:

Let $\frac{x}{2-\sqrt3}=\frac{y}{2+\sqrt3}=k$,

so $x=(2-\sqrt3)k$ and $y=(2+\sqrt3)k$

Substituting these values we get:

$\dfrac{1}{x+1}+\dfrac{1}{y+1}$

$=\dfrac{x+y+2}{xy+x+y+1}$

$=\dfrac{2(k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$

$=\dfrac{2}{k+1}$

How do I find the value of $k$?

Options for the answers are $1, \sqrt3, 2\sqrt3, 2$

If I perform backcalculation, that gives me options for k as $1, \dfrac{2-\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}$ and $\dfrac{2-2\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}$.

If we can claim that k is an integer, then we can say $k=1$ and we are done. But **can** we say k is an integer, and not any rational?

Comment: There is an error: x+y=4k, not 2k

Comment: it feels like you missed some info. Like all I am getting is $x(2+\sqrt3)=y(2-\sqrt3)\Rightarrow x=y(2-\sqrt3)^2=y(7-4\sqrt3)$, which is not enough, I guess.

Comment: Are there further conditions about $x$, $y$?

Comment: choose an arbitrary x, calculate (numerically) y for this x by the given equation, evaluate the  requested expression for this x and y and compare to the given solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a missing data, it could actually attain any value

From there you've stopped $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{y+1} = \frac{4k+2}{k^2+4k+1}$

Now, suppose $\frac{4k+2}{k^2+4k+1} = t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$, let show there is a solution for this specific t. From here $tk^2 + 4(t-1)k + (t-2) = 0$ we have $k_{1,2} = \frac{-4(t-1) \pm \sqrt{16(t-1)^2-4t(t-2)}}{2t}$.

The expression under square root is $12t^2-24t+16$ which is $12(t-1)^2 + 4$, i.e. always positive, hence there are even **two** values of $k$, which solves for any given $t$. (except for $t = 0$, then you get $k=-\frac{1}{2}$.